# No issue or No issues. Which is correct?

Tags: usage

I have a quick doubt. Which is the correct usage of English, 'No issue' or 'No issues'? When we didn't get any issue, it represents null, so, ideally it has to be 'no issue'. Please correct me.

Comment: By saying "it represents null" are you thinking of something in programming?

Comment: I assume OP's ***unspecified*** context is he wants to know what text to put in the "status" column of a customer service report or similar. So "correct grammar" is rather irrelevant, since we're not even talking about whole sentences. But personally I can't think of *any* context where ***No issue*** would look good.

Comment: I can think of a form with a field that said something like "Issue discovered", in which case "no issue" might be a good entry if you didn't find anything.

Comment: No, you have a *quick question* about something you are unsure of.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what the situation is

> P1: Were there any problems?  *( general question )*
>   P2: There were no **issues** or concerns.
>
> P1: Was there a problem finding the restaurant?  *( specific question )*
>   P2: There was no **issue** finding the restaurant, we used GPS.

Comment: The question was about *no issue(s)*, not any alternative to either one, like you have shown by *not an issue*. So I think it is not an answer, yet, though a sight edit will do I believe.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are referring to a predominantly Indian English expression, as a full sentence, which in other English dialects would rather be "No problem." (more neutral), or "No worries." (a bit informal). I understand that both "No issues." and "No issue." are frequently used.

Besides this, given the right context, there can be numerous examples for either "no issue" or "no issues" within a longer sentence, but in these cases the word "issue" is understood more concretely, as opposed to a general answer to sentences like "thanks for this" or "please do that".